# EF Core Include a view

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following relationships:

```cs
public class File
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public File Avatar { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public File Attachment { get; set; }
}

public class Collaboration
{
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
    public Account Sender { get; set; }

    public int ReceiverId { get; set; }
    public Account Receiver { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
}
```

And I end up with this query

```cs
_dataContext
    .Collaborations
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.Sender)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Company)
    .Include(x => x.Sender)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Avatar)
    .Include(x => x.Receiver)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Company)
    .Include(x => x.Receiver)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Avatar)
    .Include(x => x.Subject)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Attachment);
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to replace some of the `Include` / `ThenInclude` by a view using EF Core.

And if possible use it as

```
.Include(x => x.SenderAndCompanyInfo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
First create a sql view;

create view SenderAndCompany as
select s.Id,s.Name, s.SurName,c.CompanyName
from Sender s inner join Company c on c.Id = s.CompanyId

After creating sql view create model for it

public class SenderAndCompany
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

//Add to context
public DbSet<SenderAndCompany> SenderAndCompany { get; set; }

//map entity to view within the DbContext.OnModelCreating method
    modelBuilder
    .Entity<SenderAndCompany>()
    .ToView(nameof(SenderAndCompany))
    .HasKey(t => t.Id);

//Finally

_dataContext
    .Collaborations
    .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(x => x.Sender)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.SenderAndCompany)
        .Include(x => x.Receiver)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Avatar)
        .Include(x => x.Subject)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Attachment);
```

Comment: How do I have a link from Sender to `SenderAndCompany` in your exemple ?
Plus, I'd like to have this `SenderAndCompany` instead of the `Include(x=> x.Sender)`